# Default value for custom fields

Tags: managed-package, formula, custom-field, customsetting

I want to assign a default value to the custom fields of a custom setting. My field type is text and I am unable to find the right syntax for it with the formula editor. I am using a dev org and these custom settings are part of a managed package.

So let's say if my custom field is username I want to assign it the value "badar". Kindly let me know how to set the default value with the help of the formula editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the value as a string:

```
"badar"
```